# make your form "sticky"

Tags: php

I have a problem with my code. When I click "Submit", the error checking works fine, but the previous values disappear. What is the problem in my code? Thank you

```
<?php

$FnameErr = $LnameErr = $GenderErr = $TimeErr = $EduErr = $ApatErr = $QuoteErr = "";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if(empty($_POST["Fname"]))
    {
        $FnameErr = "Enter First Name";
    }
    else
    {
        $Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["Lname"]))
    {
        $LnameErr = "Enter Last Name";
    }
    else
    {
        $Lname = $_POST["Lname"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["gender"]))
    {
        $GenderErr = "Enter Gender";
    }
    else
    {
        $gender = $_POST["gender"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["living"]))
    {
        $ApatErr = "Enter living";
    }
    else
    {
        $living = $_POST["living"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["quote"]))
    {
        $QuoteErr = "Enter Quote";
    }
    else
    {
        $quote = $_POST["quote"];
    }
    if(empty($_POST["education"]))
    {
        $EduErr = "Enter Education";
    }
    else
    {
        $education = $_POST["education"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["TofD"]))
    {
        $TimeErr = "Enter Time";
    }
    else
    {
        $TofD = $_POST["TofD"];
    }
    if(isset($Fname) && isset($Lname) && isset($gender) && isset($living) && isset($quote) && isset($TofD))
    {

        echo "Hello, " . $Fname . " " . $Lname . ".<br />";
        echo "You are " . $gender . ", and you live in ";
        foreach($living as $f)
        {
            echo $f . "<br />";
        }

        echo "You're favorite time is " . $TofD . ", and you passed " . $education . "!<br />";
        echo "<i>" . $quote . "</i><br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This isn't a *code for me please* type of community. Please expand on what you've attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two fast ways of doing this:

1. JavaScript to early-test for values.

You have to create a JavaScript function that checks each field for content before you submit the form to PHPscript, and if no content, show some message right on the page.

1. Use PHP.

You have to add all the values to session, and then, when form is re-loaded(in case if there are no data in one of the fields), add values from session into the form. If there are no errors and form validates, you have to clear your sessions to remove values, so next time when form is loaded, no values will be added.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do this; you just have to add values to the form.

```
<input type=text name=FName value="<?php echo $FName; ?>">
```

Do something similar for each individual form input

Comment: thank you this work with input but did not work with radio buttons and menu option and txtarea and check box

Comment: @moha23 for textareas do `<textarea...>$Variable</textarea>`.  For radio buttons do `<input <?php if ($VarName) echo 'checked' ?>>`.  I'm sure you can figure it out